# Parallel for each stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, stack-overflow, html-agility-pack

I have simple code to parse `HTML` with `HtmlAgilityPack` and upload results to `SQL data server`. The thing is when I am using `foreach` loop it is working properly. I wanted to try the `Parell for each` loop. I saw, that the scraping is going faster, but I am getting (not everytime) stack overflow exception. Can you look on the code and tell me why?

```
 //for each link object
 Parallel.ForEach(link, _link =>
    {
    pageNumber=0;
    position=1;
    //try to load every single page number
        while (true)
        {
            //load page's html
            siteHtml = web.Load(_link.LinkUrl + "?page=" + pageNumber);
            try
            {
                doc.LoadHtml(siteHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section[@class='answers']")[0].InnerHtml);
                comments = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//singleAnswer");
                foreach (HtmlNode _comments in comments)
                {
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HtmlPage2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    HtmlPage2.LoadHtml(_comments.InnerHtml)

                    commentId = Convert.ToInt32(_comments.GetAttributeValue("id", ""));
                    commentValue = (HtmlPage2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='content']")[0].InnerText);

                    if (commentValue.Contains(_link.Keyword))
                    {
                        sql.updateComment(_link.LinkId, commentValue);
                        _link.Position = position;
                        _link.MyCommentId = commentId;
                        goto NextLink;
                    }
                    position++;
                }
            }

            catch
            {

            }

            if (!siteHtml.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Contains(@"class=""pagingx"" rel=""nextPage"">"))
            {
                break;
            }

        pageNumber++;
        }

        NextLink:;
        groupBox1.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
        {
            groupBox1.Text = "Link's statistics (" + finished + "/" + linksUrlElements + ")";
        }));
    });
```

I also saw that CPU usage is much higher with `Parallel for each` instead of `for each`

Comment: You are doing a ton of stuff that is not safe to multithread in your code.

Comment: So is there any way to split tasks? What I want to say is that if I run my application twice I can scrape html from 100 url's in 10 seconds. If I run only 1 instance of my application I can scrape the same amount of urls in 10 seconds. I don't want to run my application for example 5 times. I would like to split the scraping part task somehow.

Comment: You can but you can't share objects between calls. Move the code that does the processing in to a function and have it use only local variables, and have the only thing you pass in is the string for the url. That function you could call in parallel